# Adding maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How can I add maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } in settings.gradle.kts??

a red line appears under the url, the error says: Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

How can I solve this, please?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of Android Iguana, the format should be like this

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It Works For me.
build.gradle     -version

`plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.4" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.1.4" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
}`